# Does a choice of measure on $\mathfrak{g}$ induce a measure on $G$?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. One can put a (left) Haar measure $\mu$ on $G$ and a Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ which are both unique up to constants.

My question is whether fixing $\mu$ on $G$ picks out $\lambda$ uniquely on $\mathfrak{g}$ and conversely.

I think a natural first step in answering this question is to consider the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ and try to use the change of variables formula. However there are two issues that one faces:

1. The exponential map is in general a local diffeomorphism only.
2. The Lebesgue measure transferred from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $G$ via the change of variables formula need not be a Haar measure:
   $$\int_G f(g)\, d\mu(g):=\int_{\mathfrak{g}}f(\exp X) |\mathrm{Jac}\exp|\, d\lambda(X) $$

Can someone please shed some light on the relation between the measures on the Lie group and the Lie algebra and resolving the above two issues? (I think the first issue is not severe, as $\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism and that should be enough for transferring the measure from one side to the other, if at all possible for a group $G$.)

Thanks in advance for any comments/answers.

Comment: An immediate problem I see is that the Lebesgue measure is both left and right invariant (as a measure of the additive group of $\mathfrak{g}$, but in general the left and right invariant Haar measures on $G$ are not the same. A more serious problem is that $\exp$ is not a (local) homomorphism.

Comment: For a $n$-dimensional Lie group $G$ a left Haar measure is (well, up to orientation) the same as a left-invariant $n$-form on $G$, which is the same as an element of $\bigwedge^n\mathfrak g^*$, which is the same (again modulo orientation) as a Lebesgue measure on $\mathfrak g$

Comment: @user8268 I get from your comment that a choice of Haar measure on $G$ determines a Lebesgue measure on $\mathfrak{g}$ and conversely. Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Of course, that answers the question in the title of this post, but does not touch the question of how the two measures are related via the exponential map and the change of variables formula.

Comment: @PhilipM: Is the question about the Jacobian of the exponential map? It is $J(X)=\det(\int_0^1 Ad_{\exp(tX)}dt)=\det(f(ad_X))$ ($X\in\mathfrak g$), where $f(x)=(e^x-1)/x$

Comment: @user8268 no the question is not about the formula for the Jacobian. There are in fact two related questions: 1) Does a choice of Lebesgue measure on $\mathfrak{g}$ determine a measure on $G$, and vice versa? I think the answer to this question is yes, as you have explained in your above comment. The second question pushes this a bit further: 2) Does the change of variable formula (displayed in my post) define a Haar measure on $G$? If not, under what conditions on $G$ this happens?

Comment: oh I see. For 1 the answer is indeed yes, for 2 it is yes only if exp is bijective (perhaps up to a set of measure 0). I guess it's bijective iff $G$ is solvable and  1-connected; for semisimple $G$ it is going to fail.

Comment: @user8268 Do you have a reference for your answer to 2), namely that the change of variables formula defines a Haar measure on $G$ by translating the Lebesgue measure when exp is bijective? If we assume that $f$ is supported near the identity of $G$ where exp is bijective, can we say that the measure that the change of variables formula defines agrees with the Haar measure in that case? I'm trying to understand how the bijectivity of exp implies the translation invariance of $\mu$. Thanks!

Comment: @user8268 maybe one can extend the result to the case when the exponential maps the Lie algebra onto the connected component of the identity. Then one should be able to extend the measure into the other components by choosing an element of each component to translate the identity. Does the result depend on the elements one chooses?