# Measure on Lie Algebra "induced" by Haar measure on U(n)

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, haar-measure

On the unitary group $U(n)$, the Haar measure provides a suitable notion of uniformity for many applications. The Lie Group $U(n)$ is generated by the Hermitian matrices, i.e., I can write any $A \in U(n)$ as $$A = \exp(\sum_{j,k=1}^n i a_{jk}\Omega_{jk})$$
where $a_{jk}$ are real coefficients dependent on A and $\Omega_{jk}$ are the standard basis elements of the Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n) = \{X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n } | X^\dagger = X\}$.

My question is this: What is the measure "induced" on the Lie Algebra by the Haar measure on $U(n)$? Put another way: What measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ do I have to use to sample the $a_{jk}$ if I want the corresponding unitary matrices to be distributed according to the Haar measure?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want, more precisely what the expressions "sample the $a_{jk}$" and "distributed according to the Haar measure" mean exactly. Anyway, it seems that the discussion in the comments to this question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1383157/96384

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know how to sample random unitaries that are uniformly distributed w.r.t. the Haar measure (https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609050, and implemented in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.unitary_group.html). What I would like to do is sample $a_{jk}$ instead of the unitary itself (it's for a numerical application). However, I need to sample $a_{jk}$ in such a way that when I calculate the corresponding unitaries, they are distributed in the same way as if I had sampled them directly as described above. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your problem? A similar one would also be about the decomposition $A = \prod_{j,k} e^{i b_{jk}} \Omega_{jk}$ and how to sample these $b_{jk}$ (i.e. what are choices of probability distributions/measures on the $b_{jk}$) such that the resulting distribution is the Haar distribution.